# Importing numbers with leading zeros from excel into SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, excel, sql-import-wizard

I am trying to import numbers (postcodes) into a SQL DB using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. The column is text in Excel however when I import the file, the postcode column gets mapped to a float type which is causing NULL results for any values with a leading zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new column and used the excel TEXT function to reformat the postcodes.

```
=TEXT(P2,"0000")
```

Then I imported the file with the new column and the new postcode column had a default mapping to nvarchar(255).